# How to Send An Entire Xcode Project Over Email to Apple

Tags: xcode, compression

I have an Xcode project (4.6) that I am requesting technical support on from Apple. One requirement of this process is to abstract the issue that you are having into a sample Xcode project and then send them (via email) that Xcode project. I have created an Xcode project to send them by taking my original project and deleting any and all irrelevant components including all the images. I then tried to compress the Xcode file, but apparently it is still way too large to send (110mb).

Although I have seen one or two questions that have been asked on this issue, neither has received a response other than to just 'use git instead.' But given that Apple is asking me to send them an Xcode project via email, I am compelled to think that it is possible to do this.

Does have any general suggestions for how to resize an Xcode file and/or send its contents over email, in particular to Apple so that they can build and run it?

Comment: "Too big" according to what? How big is it currently? A stripped-down Xcode project should certainly fit within the (10mb?) limit on most email services.

Comment: It is 110mb.  I have no idea how it can be so large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the project zipped to a dropbox public folder and give them the URL in an email.  That way they can have access and when you're done delete the file.